# Enumeration to boolean casting question

Tags: c#, casting, enums, typeconverter

I have the following enumeration:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    MyTrue,
    MyFalse
}
```

And I'd like to eventually be able to automatically convert my enumeration to a boolean value, with a simple line like this:

```
MyEnum val = MyEnum.MyTrue;
bool IsThisTrue = val;
```

Currently, I have to do this:

```
bool IsThisTrue = val == MyEnum.MyTrue;
```

Is there some mechanism I can apply to my enumeration to allow for native enum->bool casting?  I'm wondering if some variant of a typeconverter is what I need or not.

Thanks

**Edit:**  There is a reason for my custom enumeration.  Since this properties are all eventually bound to a property grid, we have mechanisms put in place to bind all of our custom enumerations to multi-lingual strings in resources files.  We need all of the enum's we're using to be in a specific namespace, hence the "MyEnum" class.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That line would work only with an implicit static conversion operator (or maybe the more-confusing `true()` operator, but that is rarely seen in the wild). You cannot define operators on enums, so ultimately the answer is: no.

You *could*, however, write an extension method on `MyEnum` to return `true` or `false`.

```
static class MyEnumUtils {
    public static bool Value(this MyEnum value) {
        switch(value) {
            case MyEnum.MyTrue: return true;
            case MyEnum.MyFalse: return false;
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
                 // ^^^ yes, that is possible
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use `bool IsThisTrue = val.Value();`

Answer (score 16):

Write an extension method like this:

```
public static bool ToBoolean(this MyEnum value) {
    return value == MyEnum.MyTrue;
}
```

and forget about it

Comment: I'm new to the .net 3.5 world, I forgot this feature existed, I'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    MyFalse = 0,
    MyTrue = 1
}
```

then:

```
MyEnum val = MyEnum.MyTrue;
bool IsThisTrue = val;

bool IsThisTrue = Convert.ToBoolean((int)val);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It is a bit dizzying though to have to nest the functions like that in inline code. Great baseline for the accepted solution here though!